# Rails continues to iterate After elements are removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops

I have an `each` loop that I want to remove elements from as I go through it. Something like this:

```
 @list.each do |elem|
      using = elem.get_similar_elems
      using.each do |u|
          //do stuff with 'using'
       end 
      @list = @list - using
  end
```

I was thinking that the `list - using` part would remove it from the overall `.each` loop.

But instead, it continues to loop over the elements. I know that `list - using` is successful, though, because the `//do stuff` part isn't doing anything (i.e., there is nothing in `using`).

I am thinking that perhaps the `each` loop takes the collection at the beginning and `list - using` can't affect that.

So my 2 Q's are:

-1-Is that correct?

-2-How can my goal be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with `list - using` doesn't delete items from @list (I'm assuming a typo, there was no @). It simply returns the difference.
Deleting them would be `@list = @list - using`. But that means changing @list in the middle of the iteration and the behavior will be completely chaotic. You should store the similar items in a temporary array and remove them from the list when you're done iterating.

A potential implementation that may work if I understand your comments:

```
    used = []
    @list.each do |elem|    
      using = elem.get_similar_elems
      # discard elements used in previous iteration 
      # if you really want to do this, it's not clear
      using = using - used 
      # add new used elements
      used.concat using
      # do stuff with using
```

Comment: tnx for the corrections, I was doing `@list = @list - using`, I just put it wrong in here.

Comment: As for storing in a temp array...Thing is, I need to get all the similar elements for *each* element I iterate through (imagine a `list` of cars to be displayed by car-model--as we go through `list` I want to grab all the cars with that car's model…)--and then remove them from the original array so they aren't displayed again. Could be I'm just being thick, but it seems to me that using a temp array doesn't account for that. My Q was perhaps unclear?

Comment: added an example on how to implement this based on your comments

Comment: yes, this would work--tnx!
Q-Why would changing the @list in the middle of the loop be so very terrible? Also, *is* there any method to do this? I've become quite curious about it...

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what is contained in `@list`, something like this might work:

```
@list.each do |elem|
   elem.get_similar_elems.each do |u|
      //do stuff with 'using'
   end 
   @list.delete(elem)
end
```

Comment: `.delete` is not the same as using the minus same? I thought they were…Can `.delete` be used on a collection of elements? (as in `@list.delete(using)`)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just get all the similar elements at the beginning?

```
@list.flat_map(&:get_similar_elems).uniq.each do |u|
end
```

edit: I think the temp array approach other people are mentioning would look something like this (you could alternatively use a Set)

```
already_seen = []
@list.each do |elem|
  next if already_seen.include?(elem)
  using = elem.get_similar_elems
  using.each do |u|
  end
  already_seen += using
end
```

Comment: Thing is, I need to get all the similar elements for *each* element I iterate through (imagine a `list` of cars to be displayed by car-model--as we go through `list` I want to grab all the cars with that car's model...)